# What difference is there between rescuing Lisa or waiting for the concert to finish?

Tags: persona-2-innocent-sin

After you regain control after you learn the stress Lisa has been going though your given a choice to go in a rescue Lisa or wait

Since I saved before then I check both options: saving her leads to a battle with Price Taurus with just 3 party members, while waiting gives you 5, also, rescuing her has you see the Prince use one of Joker's Skulls while waiting as you learn that the entire park is rigged with bombs and King Leo appears.

According to walkthroughs by waiting you can get Ero+ later on but I honestly want to rush in and save her.

So I want to know, after I beat the Prince, is there any other changes to the story or does both options lead to the scene after the boss battle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you save her or wait for the conclusion of the concert they both lead to the same scene...